# How to make a template class object as a tuple?

Tags: c++, class, templates

```
class Farmacie
{
    string proprietar;
    string denumire;
    int angajati;
    vector<int>profit;
    public:
        Farmacie(){}
};
class Farmacie_online:public Farmacie
{
    string proprietar;
    string web;
    int nr_vizitatori;
    int discount;
    public:
        Farmacie_online(){}
        Farmacie_online(string a,string b,int c, int d){
            this->proprietar=a;
            this->web=b;
            this->nr_vizitatori=c;
            this->discount=d;
        }
};
template <typename T,typename ...rest>
class GestionareFarmacii
{
    static int index;
    int id;
    T* date;
    public:
        GestionareFarmacii(int nr, int id){this->id=id;this->date=new T[nr];}
        GestionareFarmacii operator+=(const Farmacie_online& f)
        {
            this->date[index].first=f.web;
            this->date[index].second=f.nr_vizitatori;
            this->date[index].third=f.discount;
            index++;
            return *this;
        }

};
int main()
{
    Farmacie_online f("blabla","www.fs",25,50);
    GestionareFarmacii <tuple<string,int,int>>farm(10,23);
    farm+=f;
}
```

I can't get it from the internet how you are supposed to use this stuff, it is mandatory to use classes and the `id` from the template is just a constant for the whole template. I know the += is very wrong, I don't know how to make that, I was trying to show what I want to do basically, to add a `farmacie_online` object to the template object array thing

Comment: I'm trying to understand what "_How to make a template class object as a tuple?_" means and the code doesn't help me. Are you talking about `std::tuple`?

Comment: So basically I need the code in main() to work, like have multiple `farmacie_online` objects and to make `GestionareFarmacii <tuple<string,int,int>>farm(10,23);` something like this and then add a number of `farmacie_online` objects to the `farm`

Comment: It needs to be something of type vector<tuple<web, nr_vizitatori, discount>>

Comment: Why do you want to use `tuple` in your template? Seems like you are trying to make your `date` a `tuple<string, int, int>`

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that line all the way down there. So, `T = tuple<string,int,int>` and `rest...` is empty.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that could work, but I don't know how to write it like that

Comment: `rest...` I don't know, I left it there by mistake, I tried some stuff from the internet, didn't work, but yes, date/T should be that type basically

Comment: Ok, so, you allocate `date = new T[nr];` in one place and in another you're trying to assign `first`, `second` and `third` in the tuple. Those member variables don't exist. Look here what you can use: [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

Comment: The task goes something like this: `built the classes as I did there, then make a template class  with the current index, automatically updated, a constant id and an object structure dynamically allocated. Overload += to insert a new farmacie_online object to the structure and use vector <tuple<web, nr_vizitatori, discount>>`

Comment: I don't get the stuff with std::tuple how to connect it to the += operator overloading, if I do it like that, what do I initialize the GestionareFarmacii <> farm to, the task above is basically all I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::tuple` doesn't have accessor like `.first` and `.second`. Instead, you would need to use `std::get<INDEX>(yourTuple)` to access each elements.

If you want to assign each item separately, you could do:

```
std::get<0>(date[index]) = f.web;
std::get<1>(date[index]) = f.nr_vizitatori;
std::get<2>(date[index]) = f.discount;
```

Or, you can also create a tuple object with `std::make_tuple` with your values:

```
date[index] = std::make_tuple(f.web, f.nr_vizitatori, f.discount)
```

---

Side note, you could have you template set up as:

```
template<typename ...T>
class GF
{
    ⋮
    tuple<T...>* date;
    ⋮
    GF(int nr, int id)
    {
        ⋮
        date = new tuple<T...>[nr];
    }
    ⋮
}
```

And in your main, you can will it as `GF<string, int, int> farm(10 ,23)`

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against using raw pointers here (or anywhere). A vector of tuple would be much safer and easier to use.

Comment: @Kyle I would agree the same. I'm only using raw pointer because op had that, and his question was regarding to using `tuple` and "How to make a template...."